# What are the top databases per country?

Tags: discussion, survey-2017

I left a public copy of Stack Overflow 2017 survey dataset in BigQuery:

- https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/fh-bigquery:stackoverflow.survey_results_public_2017?tab=details

How can I find the top databases per country?

Answer (score 3):

To find the top databases per country that people want to work on:

```
SELECT Country, c
  , ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT value, count, ROUND(100*count/SUM(count) OVER(PARTITION BY Country), 2) percent FROM UNNEST(v)
  ) v
FROM (
  SELECT Country, APPROX_TOP_COUNT(v, 10) v, COUNT(*) c
  FROM (
    SELECT Country, SPLIT(WantWorkDatabase, '; ') v
    FROM `fh-bigquery.stackoverflow.survey_results_public_2017`
  ), UNNEST(v) v
  WHERE v!='NA'
  GROUP BY 1
  HAVING c>10
  ORDER BY c DESC
)
ORDER BY c DESC
```

It's interesting to observe the variations between different countries.

The US top interests are PostgreSQL, SQL Server, and MongoDB:

[image]

While India is not very interested in PostgreSQL:

[image]

And the UK is very interested in SQL Server:

[image]

And Germany has both MySQL and PostgreSQL on top:

[image]

Most countries are not very interested in Cassandra or Oracle, but Israel shows a surprising interest for Cassandra:

[image]

While Pakistan shows above average interest for Oracle:

[image]

Charting the interest for MySQL, MongoDB and PostgreSQL:

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

And the rest, on an [interactive Data Studio dashboard](https://datastudio.google.com/c/org/UTgoe29uR0C3F1FBAYBSww/reporting/0ByGAKP3QmCjLeU1Fek5hWHRyeUU/page/YxvF%20(built%20with%20DataStudio)).

(feel free to tag me on https://twitter.com/felipehoffa)